# Why itertools.groupby() is significantly slower than the equivalent approach using defaultdict?

Tags: python, performance

I wanted to check which is faster between `groupby()` and a custom recipe based on `defaultdict` to group data:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

def g1(data):
    groupdict = defaultdict(list)
    for value in data:
        group = value[0]
        value = value[1]
        groupdict[group].append(value)
    return [(key, ''.join(values)) for key, values in groupdict.items()]

def g2(data):
    extractKey = lambda x: x[0]
    aggregate = lambda g: ''.join(x[1] for x in g)
    #return [(k, aggregate(g)) for k, g in groupby(data, extractKey)]
    return [(k, aggregate(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=extractKey), extractKey)]

import random

keys = list(range(1,100))
vals = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

data = [(random.choice(keys), random.choice(vals)) for _ in range(1000)]
#data.sort()

import timeit

for g in ('g1', 'g2'):
    print(g, timeit.timeit(g + '(data)', number=1000, globals=globals()))
```

To my surprise, `groupby()` is almost 3 times slower than `defaultdict`.

> g1 0.17048488299769815
>
> g2 0.47328821099654306

Even if the data is pre-sorted, i.e. **we do not count the time spent for `sort()`ing** (uncomment the two commented lines), where supposedly `groupby()` should perform **faster** than the other recipe, it is almost 1.5 times as slower.

> g1 0.17607520399906207
>
> g2 0.2464493800071068

Why? Is there some optimization in `g2` that I did overlook?

Comment: In one version you are sorting. Sorting is expensive.

Comment: @KlausD. for one, it's slower even **without** sorting. Also, `dict`s use binary search trees, hash trees or similar data structure, so each lookup should be O(log n) (documentation says the amortized worst case is O(n), I don't get that)

Comment: I suspect it's because of the the function call overhead for your two lambdas. Inline code is always faster than a function call. I don't have any timings to back this up though. Not sure how much of a difference it really makes.

Comment: Sadly, `groupby` isn't known for being speedy. BTW, you can replace `extractKey` with `operator.itemgetter(0)`, which should be somewhat faster.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring, itemgetter(0) is about 10-15% faster, however that does not make quite a difference.

Comment: Also note, `groupby` has advantages in the memory constrained case where the values are being produced on the fly; you can process the groups in a streaming fashion, without storing them; `defaultdict` will require the memory to store *all* of them. When memory isn't an issue, `defaultdict` will often win, even when the input is presorted, because they're both algorithmically equivalent on runtimes (`O(n)`), and `groupby` has some per-element overhead that the `dict` approach can avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the overhead of the `lambda` call compared to just indexing into a tuple.

If you rewrite your first case to use `extractKey`:

```
def g1(data):
    groupdict = defaultdict(list)
    extractKey = lambda x: x[0]
    for value in data:
        group = extractKey(value)
        value = value[1]
        groupdict[group].append(value)
    return [(key, ''.join(values)) for key, values in groupdict.items()]
```

Then they're both just about the same speed (in the non-sorting case).